# Not able to run isql on cygwin : env var misconfigured?

Tags: cygwin, sap-ase, isql

There is another similar discussion on stackoverflow but the error message is slightly different, and the solution given did not work for me.

Here is my case :
I just installed cygwin on a windows 7 workstation.
I also copied from a linux server the "sybase" directory. ( meaning the one designated by $SYBASE )

Then i updated SYBASE env var on my workstation and i also updated all paths in `SYBASE.sh`. 
Then i ran it. It gave no error message.

However, isql does not run properly and produce this output :

> The context allocation routine failed when it tried to load localization files!!
>   One or more following problems may caused the failure
>
> Your sybase home directory is /home/xxx/sybase. Check the environment variable SYBASE if it is not the one you want!
>
> Cannot access file /home/xxx/sybase\ini\objectid.dat
>   An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related structures.

All paths exists and are accessible except `home/xxx/sybase\ini\objectid.dat`

This must be part of the explanation :
my objectid.dat file is in a **config** folder, not an **ini** one.
Also there is a mismatch in the slash and backslash in the path itself.

Just like if there was a mix between windows and cygwin environment...

Comment: Does the `$SYBASE` directory contain binaries or only config (txt, ini, etc.) information?

Comment: from `https://www.cygwin.com/` : Cygwin is not: 

    a way to run native Linux apps on Windows. You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.

Comment: There seems to have configuration + binaries. including isql or interface file. looks like there is everything